# Can you "propose an opinion"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context, verbs

I've been trying to rack my brain around a simple sentence that I feel was misconstrued in a discussion I was having.

I wanted for a certain discussion topic to "propose an opinion" that would end up relating back to an earlier discussion.

Is it improper to use "propose" here?

I'll try my best to add context to the conversation.

Me: Claim of X.

Them: Dismissal based on the wording of X.

Me: Question based on Y, that depending on the answer would be an example of X.

Them: Dismissal based on the controversy of Y.

Me: I chose the controversy surrounding Y, to propose an opinion on Y (that would strengthen my claim of X).

Them: That's not how you use the word propose.

Comment: No. Idiomatically, you [***venture** an opinion*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+ventured+an+opinion%2CI+proposed+an+opinion&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20ventured%20an%20opinion%3B%2Cc0) (or maybe ***advance*** it) - you don't ***propose*** it. A couple of centuries ago, a tiny fraction of competent speakers / writers might have proposed opinions, but I doubt any would today.

Comment: What are your thoughts on these usages of the phrase [propose an opinion](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22propose+an+opinion%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&tbm=bks&prmd=niv&sxsrf=ALiCzsb2Z8EHJav_4sDgkUTZXwGflrMLDQ:1660842932146&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjc4P2H8tD5AhVFcDwKHb13C0EQpwV6BAgBECY&biw=412&bih=670&dpr=2.63)?

Comment: Examples with X and Y are much harder to follow than examples with real words. Without knowing roughly what X and Y are, the logic is quite difficult to follow, and many readers will just give up rather than attempt to answer your question. Consider replacing the original values of X and Y, or at least comparable alternatives.

Comment: I propose an opinion [on this subject] be published on our website. "I would like to propose my opinion as a solution to the problem here." And I think: "to propose an opinion on Y" is fine.  You can propose your opinion to the group or just remain silent.

Comment: *The CHAIRMAN expressed his thanks to Mr. Eckersley for his interesting remarks and asked if everybody **agreed not to propose an opinion** but merely to recommend a continuation of studies .* https://books.google.it/books?id=DOdvxeVsT5UC&pg=RA1-PA288&dq=%22propose+an+opinion%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9luKkgdH5AhXghP0HHQZfAZkQ6AF6BAgFEAM#v=onepage&q=%22propose%20an%20opinion%22&f=false

Comment: *In Natural Science , and for the sake of investi . gating a principle , **it may be found convenient to propose an opinion** , before we either ascertain or arrange phenomena . But the case of Theology is very different .* https://books.google.it/books?id=ThsEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA261&dq=%22propose+an+opinion%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9luKkgdH5AhXghP0HHQZfAZkQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%22propose%20an%20opinion%22&f=false

Comment: Per my first comment, it ***wasn't unknown*** for people to ***propose** an opinion* 200 years ago. But as the link in that first comment shows, with the specific subject ***I***, the usage didn't occur often enough to plot on a chart even back then. As [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ventured+an+opinion%2Cproposed+an+opinion&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cventured%20an%20opinion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cproposed%20an%20opinion%3B%2Cc0) shows, with no specific subject there are enough instances to chart, but ***it was always rare***.

Comment: @user66974: The examples you quote are hopelessly outdated, and it's misleading to put them in front of people who almost certainly want to learn ***current*** English, not "pre-Victorian" usages.

Comment: I find the X and Y very confusing.  I don't really understand what "Claim of X" means..  I don't understand the context of "them" (who are they)  saying "Dismissal of X".  The example you give isn't clear

Answer (score 2):

One might well propose an argument, or propose a topic for discussion, or a basis for discussion. One might propose a theory or an idea. One might advance an opinion, or offer an opinion for discussion, or more likely simply state an opinion. If an opinion is tentative, one might venture it.

Whatever might have been the case in the past, a fluent speaker now would be very unlikely to say:

> I want to propose the opinion that ....

or any similar form where the noun "*opinion*" is the object of the verb "*propose*".

Instead of the form in the question:

> I chose the controversy surrounding Y, to propose an opinion on Y (that would strengthen my claim of X). [image: Red X, indicating non-standard usage]

one might say something like:

> I chose the controversy surrounding Y, to suggest an idea on Y (that would strengthen my claim of X).  [image: Green check-mark, indicating a standard or common usage]

Perhaps that or a similar form would cover the intended use here.

Comment: A speaker might very well say: I would like to propose my opinion or an opinion that is quite different from the ones given so far.

Answer (score 1):

There  are at least 5 cases of "*propose an opinion*" [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22propose%20an%20opinion%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)  and an important number of "*opinions(,) proposed*", where "opinions" is the object, [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22opinions%20proposed%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

So, apparently, it is correct to "propose an opinion". Yet if we  examine carefully   what an opinion is  we might not agree.  The  definition  of  this concept from the  SOED follows.

> **opinion 1.** A view held about a particular subject or point; a judgement; a belief

We turn now  to the definition  of "propose".

> **propose 1.** Put forward as a scheme or plan, suggest (a thing)

Matching the  terms,  for X to propose opinion  Y amounts to X, in the first case, affirming that what is thought about a certain subject or point (Y) is a plan or scheme.  This is  clearly not so. In the  second it amounts to  affirming that what is thought about a certain subject or point (Y) is being  suggested  as a possible realization, a thing potentially in the being so to speak. Clearly, you can't propose  to someone that a certain opinion  held by someone or other should become reality, it is already a fully formed reality in  someone's mind.

Thus, provided there  is no flaw in the foregoing reasoning, it is not a good idea to "propose an opinion".

Answer (score 0):

"Propose" means to suggest that something might exist, or suggest that someone take some action. It makes no sense either to suggest that an opinion might exist, or to suggest that someone choose to have a certain opinion.

Comment: I can't agree that "it makes no sense". The usage ***did*** occur a long time ago, albeit infrequently at best. It's just hopelessly outdated / non-idiomatic today.

Answer (score -2):

Spoken English, for example:

I should like to propose an opinion on this matter that might resolve our quandary here.

I want to propose a different opinion on this subject, if I may.

Written English, for example:
The opinions we proposed on the subject of over-taxation at the meeting were not well received.

Opinions proposed for consideration have all been recorded in the minutes.

[Never say never]

propose here is the same as put forth, advanced, spoken, given

Comment: Are these from some source, or creations of your own? I will say that they all seem a bit odd to me.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I will not argue in favor of each one. That said, none of them is odd. It really bugs me when sentences that are perfectly legitimate in English receive a comment such as the one you wrote. It is very misleading for learners.